# How can I view details for a specific process using the Process Monitor on Windows?

Tags: windows, process-monitor, process-monitoring

I want to use the [Sysinterals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to inspect a specific process on my Windows computer.

Is there a way to search the running processes by the path to the executable or by PID?

I tried using the Find tool and the Filter tool, and I didn't have any luck with either. I also thought perhaps I could sort the threads/processes by one of the columns, but sorting by column is not possible.

I am using version 3.89.

(For reference, this is to help me debug [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71574770/8593689), but asking for help using software is off topic on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Did you try right clicking and selecting properties?  Then there are informative tabs that come up.

Comment: Of course that sorting by column is possible!

Comment: @harrymc When I click or double click any of the columns, nothing happens.

Comment: @John I am trying to search for the process I am interested in first. Once I've found it in the list, I can view the details as you say. But scrolling through the processes to find the one I want would be difficult, as I have hundreds of running processes. So I was hoping I could use some find or filter tool to narrow down my linear search.

Comment: "Find" works as well - I just used it

Comment: My Find wasn't working (it would either have an ETA much longer than I was willing to wait, or it would find events for old processes that had exited), but it started working after I cleared the events that had been captured. I was able to search by PID.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use the filters button and filter by PID which can be found from task manager or autohotkey window spy.

*My find also was listing 132 hours.. sorry for no comment, whole rep system that ruined the site and all*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).